# Why is the logic probe reducing current from the power supply?

Tags: crystal, troubleshooting, probe

I am troubleshooting a very basic circuit using an inexpensive logic probe to check values. Typically when I use the probe I see current output go up about 7mA, which I assume is to power the sound and light.

There is one particular pin where I should be getting a signal, and when I use the probe the current actually decreases, significantly. It goes from 43mA down to 26mA.

Why would the current decrease when the logic probe is hitting this pin?

This is pin XTAL1 on 80C31 microprocessor, see diagram. There is a crystal, two capacitors, and the microprocessor itself. I'm not getting signal on XTAL1.

[image]

Comment: XTAL1 is the crystal oscillator input.  Probably not a good idea to probe this pin.  XTAL2 is the output so better if you must probe the XTAL at all.  But any probe you touch to either pin will add to the load capacitance.

Comment: @AlmostDone in normal operation would you expect signals on both XTAL1 and XTAL2?  (Why not a good idea?)

Comment: The input is hi-Z as is the Xtal circuit.  The probe causes more loading on this node than on the output which is a lower Z.  I would expect to see a rounded square wave on the input, assuming your probe doesn't load it so much that it quits oscillating.  On the output, a square wave with faster rise and fall times.

Comment: Keep in mind that even a scope probe on a crystal input can load it enough for it to stop working (~10pF or thereabouts). Your logic probe is likely a much lower impedance than a x10 scope probe and is loading that crystal input even more.

Comment: Logic probes may only have a 10 K input impedance, expecting a logic signal. Even CD4000 series could source about 1 mA. Xtal is not a good place to probe anyways.

Comment: `in normal operation would you expect signals on both XTAL1 and XTAL2?` ... yes, but not at logic levels

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why would the current decrease when the logic probe is hitting this pin?

The added load from the probe causes the oscillator circuit to run at a much lower speed than normal, or stops it entirely. Since the microcontroller is now running at a much lower speed (or not running at all), it consumes less current.